# php get variable value and append it to a query in a dynamic manner

Tags: php, laravel

I am not sure how to say this, but you will get the idea from the below code. Laravel framework is used.
My code is as shown below:

```
$keywords = ProductKeyword::orderBy('name', 'asc')->pluck('name')->toArray();
if (!empty($keywords)) {
    $str = '';
    foreach ($keywords as $key => $keyword) {
        if ($key == 0) {
            $str .= "Where('description', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')";                    
        } else {
            $str .= "->orWhere('description', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')";
        }
    }
}
$str .= "->all()";

$items = Item::$str;
dd($items);
```

I need the value of `$str` to be appended to `Item` model, so that in effect the php interprets this as below

```
$items = Item::Where('description', 'like', '%' . 'laptop' . '%')->orWhere('description', 'like', '%' . 'pc' . '%')->all();
```

So that I can dynamically create where-clauses.

Comment: Code and data are different things. You should learn to properly differentiate between the two.

Comment: @CBroe: yup, i agree with u, but i was just wondering if there is something specific for this in php to achieve what i was trying to do or something close enough..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things a little here. Grab the *collection* of keywords, and iterate those, then use `orWhere()` on the keywords name, and *voila*. Open up a query on your items with the `query()` method, then apply `orWhere()` for each iteration. Laravel will handle the rest. Once done, you just need to `get()` your data!

```php
$keywords = ProductKeyword::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();

$items = Item::query();
foreach ($keywords as $key => $keyword) {
    $items->orWhere('description', 'like', '%'.$keyword->name.'%');
}

$items = $items->get();
dd($items);
```

Note that if there are no keywords, it will essentially become `Item::all()`, since you do not apply any where-clauses.

Comment: But just thought though....is it any possible to append things like that need not necessarily be related to eloquents....

Comment: You mean appending it as strings as you attempted in your question, and then applying it? Well, you can to an extent call it dynamically, but only the method name. Have a look at [Variable Functions in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php). Although I do not recommend using variable functions if there are ways around it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to improve and fix your code:

```
  $query = Item::query();
  foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
     $query->orWhere('description', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%');
  }
  $result=$query->get();
```

Comment: Some more specific explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Do you perhaps want to explain why this "improves and fixes" the code, rather than just dumping some code?

Answer (score 0):

you are using a complex way to achieve it. my answer would be almost same as @Qirel

```
//prepare your query
$query = Item::query();
  foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
     //loop through the keywords in the description column of Item Table match the records which will be available in the $query
     $query->orWhere('description', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%');
  }
  // get the records which are matched and store it in $result variable
  $result=$query->get();`enter code here`
```